# boostrap collapse in while loop returns one result

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to order a list of items in sections. The section number and title are on one table and the section contents are on another table. Using a while loop inside another while loop, I want to get the section name and number. On the second while loop I want to get the section contents. The section contents has a column named section number which I pass to the query to get the right content for the appropriate sections. My problem is I'm only getting the first section and only one content for the first section. The result should be 5 contents under section 1 and 6 contents under section 2. I have seen similar questions and solutions using arrays but I can't get it to work for me since I'm still a novice.

Here's my query:

```
$host   = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'myDB';
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=myDB;host=localhost', $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$i = 0;
$j= 0;
$cId = $_GET['cId'];

$z_content = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `cur_sections` WHERE `course_id` ='$cId'");
$z_content->execute();

while($obj = $z_content->fetch())
{
    $section_no = $obj['sect_num'];
    $section_name = $obj['section_name'];
    $i++;

    echo '<div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <a   data-toggle="collapse" href="#demo'.$i.'" ><div 
    class="section_bck">
    Section '.$section_no.': <b>'.$section_name.'</b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" style="float:right;"></i></div></a>
    </div>';

    $p_content = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `course_material` WHERE `sect_num` ='$section_no' AND course_id='$cId'");
    $p_content->execute();

    while($obj2 = $p_content->fetch())
    {
        $j++;
        $lecture_title = $obj2['lecture_title'];
        $type_f = $obj2['file_type'];

        echo '
        <div id="demo'.$i.'" class ="collapse">
            <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <div class="section_bck_alt">
                    <i class="fa fa-'.$type_f.'"></i>&nbsp&nbspLecture '.$j.': '.$lecture_title.'
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The value for `$cId` is `3` which i get from the page url.
**database structure**

**Table 1:**

[image: Table 1]

**Table 2:**

[image: Table 2]

I have just found out the cause of the problem. Bootstrap collapse is somehow hiding the rest of my query result. Even tho i’ve used an incremental value to change the div ID. When i remove div collapse from the loop, all results are returned, except the fact that i can no longer hide content.

Comment: Is it because you have in your second SQL - `\`sect_num\` ='1' AND `

Comment: i did that to test the query, i have changed it back to `$section_no` but its the same result

Comment: Please share database screenshot and let me know $cid value... So I can help you.

Comment: @TanmayPatel Thanks, i've added the information to my question

Comment: SQL Injection alert. Do not pass $_GET to SQL. Use prepared statement, and positional parameters.

Comment: Also, why won't you do a proper join, to fetch all the data at once?

Comment: I never needed JOIN syntax yet, so i never learned. i’m still learning

Comment: Found the cause, please see question update

Comment: Well you are creating multiple collapsible elements inside your inner while loop (which means you have created invalid duplicate ids, as soon as this inner loop iterates more than once), but you are creating only one control element for those in the outer loop to begin with, so how exactly do you suppose that to work? You probably want to output the opening and closing tags of the collapsible element _around_ your inner loop, and only the actual data inside of it.

Comment: @connor991 I have tested your code with database I have made database in our localhost using screenshot you have attached... Here It's looks perfect I think see below screenshot link. I think you have to need double check database structure... http://prntscr.com/j244qh

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you read from the correct database? Because you define variables but never use them:

```
$host   = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'myDB';
....
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=myDB;host=localhost', $username, $password);
```

And use prepare but pass params into execute: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php